# How do you concat pandas dataframe headers into one header?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet with the first two rows as headers. Some contain information, others do not:
[image]

I would like to combine the headers into one like so:
[image]

I have tried to use join, however this reuses the last value in the first header and combines it with the second header:

```
x= pd.read_excel("x.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", header=[0,1])
x.columns = x.columns.map(' '.join)
```

Comment: Do your column headers get imported like Unamed:0_level_1 or something on import?

Comment: Yep, if I don't do the join, anything without a value has Unnamed: 0_level_n